# Why do conditionals inside of an event listener not work?

Tags: javascript, html, image, directory

When I have the conditionals inside of an event listener inside of a function, they don't seem to work properly [I commented them in]. In fact they don't work at all, but when I delete the conditionals everything works (except it works incorrectly because I need the conditionals) I'm a lot more familiar with Java if that helps in the explanation.

```
var board = document.getElementById("checkersBoard");
var isRedHighlighted = false;
var isBlackHighlighted = false;
var lastClick;
board.addEventListener("click", function(e)
{

    //alert(e.target.src);

    if(isBlackHighlighted || isRedHighlighted)
    {
        if(isBlackHighlighted)
        {
            e.target.src= "Directory/BlackPiece.png";
            lastClick.src = "Directory/BlankSpace.png";
            isBlackHighlighted = false;
        }
        if(isRedHighlighted)
        {
            e.target.src= "Directory/RedPiece.png";
            lastClick.src = "Directory/BlankSpace.png";
            isRedHighlighted = false;
        }

    }

    else
    {
        if (e.target.src == "Directory/BlackPiece.png") // why does this not work
        {
            e.target.src = "Directory/BlackPieceH.png"
            lastClick = e.target;
            isBlackHighlighted = true;
        }

        if (e.target.src == "Directory/RedPiece.png")  // why does this not work
        {
            e.target.src = "Directory/RedPieceH.png"
            lastClick = e.target;
            isRedHighlighted = true;
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Because you should be using `e.target.getAttribute('src');` judging the strings you're comparing against.

Comment: thanks if you want to put that into an answer I could mark it

Comment: more info:  target.src will return the FULL path whereas target.getAttribute('src') returns the text assigned to it.  This difference is important to know with working with relative paths. It doesn't work because you are comparing a full and relative path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the strings you're comparing against, such as: `"Directory/BlackPiece.png"`, it seems that you're intending to compare the variable(s) against the value of the `src` attribute (`e.target.getAttribute('src')`), rather than the `src` *property* (`e.target.src`).

This would yield a comparison such as, for example:

```
e.target.getAttribute('src') = "Directory/BlackPiece.png";
```

The difference between the two is that the `src` *attribute* looks at the attribute-value found within, and retrieves the value from, the specified attribute.

Whereas the `src` *property* resolves to an absolute URL, which would give a value similar to: `http://www.example.com/Directory/BlackPiece.png`.

References:

- [`Element.getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute).
- [`HTMLImageElement.src`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement).